# How to revert the list to the beginning on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Trying to use Button to sort the int value list, it works when ascending the order, but it doesn't work when going back to the original state by pressing the `Sort Value` button once more, stuck.

[Initial Outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2LLM.png)

[Outcome after `Sort Value` button pressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XFqGy.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class Product {
  final String name;
  final String category;
  final int value;

  Product({
    required this.name,
    required this.category,
    required this.value,
  });
}

List<Product> productlist = [
  Product(name: 'Sandwich', category: 'Food', value: 2),
  Product(name: 'Fish', category: 'Food', value: 1),
  Product(name: 'Vegetable', category: 'Food', value: 9),
  Product(name: 'Meat', category: 'Food', value: 13),
  Product(name: 'Book', category: 'Item', value: 4),
  Product(name: 'Hammer', category: 'Item', value: 6),
  Product(name: 'Pen', category: 'Item', value: 5),
  Product(name: 'Car', category: 'Vehicle', value: 8),
  Product(name: 'Bike', category: 'Vehicle', value: 14),
  Product(name: 'Motor', category: 'Vehicle', value: 0),
  Product(name: 'Boat', category: 'Vehicle', value: 25),
];

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final List<String> categories = ['Food', 'Item', 'Vehicle'];
  List<String> selectedCategories = [];
  bool isActive = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final filterProducts = productlist.where((product) {
      return selectedCategories.isEmpty ||
          selectedCategories.contains(product.category);
    }).toList();
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Fitler Sorting"),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                        flex: 3,
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: categories
                              .map((category) => FilterChip(
                                  selected:
                                      selectedCategories.contains(category),
                                  label: Text(category),
                                  onSelected: (selected) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      if (selected) {
                                        selectedCategories.add(category);
                                      } else {
                                        selectedCategories.remove(category);
                                      }
                                    });
                                  }))
                              .toList(),
                        )),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                          /** */
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              if (isActive) {
                                productlist
                                    .sort((b, a) => b.value.compareTo(a.value));
                              } else {
                                productlist.toList();
                              }
                            });
                          },
                          child: const Text('Sort Value, \nLow to High',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10))),
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
            Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: filterProducts.length,
                    itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                      final product = filterProducts[index];
                      return Card(
                          elevation: 8,
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
                            child: ListTile(
                                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                                title: Text(
                                  product.name,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ),
                                subtitle: Text(
                                  '${product.value}',
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                )),
                          ));
                    })))
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

I need to arrange the order ascendingly, then revert the whole list, rinse and repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the list is first created or modified save a copy of it in another variable, like for example

```
originalList = productlist.toList();
```

so your program becomes

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: MyApp()));
}

class Product {
  final String name;
  final String category;
  final int value;

  Product({
    required this.name,
    required this.category,
    required this.value,
  });
}

List<Product> productlist = [
  Product(name: 'Sandwich', category: 'Food', value: 2),
  Product(name: 'Fish', category: 'Food', value: 1),
  Product(name: 'Vegetable', category: 'Food', value: 9),
  Product(name: 'Meat', category: 'Food', value: 13),
  Product(name: 'Book', category: 'Item', value: 4),
  Product(name: 'Hammer', category: 'Item', value: 6),
  Product(name: 'Pen', category: 'Item', value: 5),
  Product(name: 'Car', category: 'Vehicle', value: 8),
  Product(name: 'Bike', category: 'Vehicle', value: 14),
  Product(name: 'Motor', category: 'Vehicle', value: 0),
  Product(name: 'Boat', category: 'Vehicle', value: 25),
];

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final List<String> categories = ['Food', 'Item', 'Vehicle'];
  List<String> selectedCategories = [];
  final originalList = productlist.toList();
  bool isActive = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final filterProducts = productlist.where((product) {
      return selectedCategories.isEmpty ||
          selectedCategories.contains(product.category);
    }).toList();
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Fitler Sorting"),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                        flex: 3,
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                          children: categories
                              .map((category) => FilterChip(
                              selected:
                              selectedCategories.contains(category),
                              label: Text(category),
                              onSelected: (selected) {
                                setState(() {
                                  if (selected) {
                                    selectedCategories.add(category);
                                  } else {
                                    selectedCategories.remove(category);
                                  }
                                });
                              }))
                              .toList(),
                        )),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        /** */
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              if (isActive) {
                                productlist
                                    .sort((b, a) => b.value.compareTo(a.value));
                              } else {
                                productlist = originalList.toList();
                              }
                              isActive = !isActive;
                            });
                          },
                          child: const Text('Sort Value, \nLow to High',
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10))),
                    ),
                  ],
                )),
            Expanded(
                child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: filterProducts.length,
                    itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                      final product = filterProducts[index];
                      return Card(
                          elevation: 8,
                          margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue),
                            child: ListTile(
                                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: 10, vertical: 10),
                                title: Text(
                                  product.name,
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ),
                                subtitle: Text(
                                  '${product.value}',
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  ),
                                )),
                          ));
                    })))
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work, check my edited question above there.

Comment: @NormAnony as I was afraid you are not actually toggling `isActive`. I edited the answer to show the full solution

Comment: what the... fuck. How?
Is this ```isActive = !isActive;``` what it's missing?
I think I just tossed this aside

Comment: I see it ain't just creating a new list as well

Comment: yeah probably will do